# Advice with post method

Tags: android, post

I'm so close to solving the [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) connection, but still after onclicked nothing has happend, no error, no freeze. What is wrong here? Or maybe in my PHP code?

```
final String suma = Float.valueOf(zam.getSuma()).toString();

ib_wyslij.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         new MyAsyncTask().execute(suma);
    }
});

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {

        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.kuba.ro/exeConn.php");

        try {
            // Add your data

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Zam_suma",
                    valueIWantToSend));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
}
```

Part of my PHP file:

```
$Zam_suma = $_POST['Zam_suma'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Zamowienie(Zam_suma) VALUES($Zam_suma)");
```

Comment: I'm sure you can come up with a more descriptive title than *"so close to sending data"*...?

Comment: Arjan, lack of ideas :P srry

Comment: That's a lame excuse, really. Just like the placeholder text says: *"What's your programming question? Be specific."* Success!

Comment: what is your php code? also the url you are posting to http://www.kuba.ro/exeConn.php is not working

Comment: after execution of exeConn.php nothing has happening normally, it should insert values into db ;)

Comment: the url you are posting to kuba.ro/exeConn.php is not working,also in debugger mode do you see a new ASyncTask process?

Comment: no i don't see ASyncTask process this url is fake

Comment: So your ASyncTask isn't running you should check the example in @ph1leas answer

Comment: e.printStackTrace() shows nothing, i can't make annotation @Override becouse the method onPostExecute(Double) of type Send.MyAsyncTask must override or implement a supertype method. I've changed MyAsyncTask for private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> and still nothing

Answer (score 1):

1. For what do you need the params Integer and Double in your asynctask? If you only need the asynctask to post the string, you can use `Void` for the other parameters:

   ```
   private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
   ```
2. Add the `@Override` annotation to the `onPostExecute()` to override the method (see Arjan's answer).
3. Call `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch blocks to see when, where and why an error occurs.
4. [Good tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask)

Comment: As an aside: adding `@Override` doesn't magically override anything. It does, however, tell the compiler you intend to override something, so it can tell you if you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

For your PHP file:

1. Be sure to validate the posted item via PHP, that you are receiving the right value using
   [`is_int`](http://php.net/is_int) [`is_string`](http://php.net/is_string), etc.

If your value is supposed to be int, use the following code example.

```
if (is_int($_POST['example_value']) {
    $value = $_POST['example_value'];
}
```

Also you should not use mysql_query, because it's nearly deprecated. Instead, you should use [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: could you give me an example of that ?